# How i close python but keep execute running

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have two buttons that call a shortcut, but I need to close python running but the program who was call keep running. Because everytime I press the button the python close and the proccess never keep going

Any idea?

Thanks.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def vulkan():
    os.startfile (r"F:\\Games\\RetroArch\\retroarch_vulkan.lnk")
    root.quit()

def default():
    os.startfile (r"F:\\Games\\RetroArch\\retroarch_gl.lnk")
    root.quit()

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Pick your choise")

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x_coordinate = (screen_width/2) - (WIDTH/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2) - (HEIGHT/2)

root.geometry ("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#frame = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=1, bd=10)
frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=10)
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.95, anchor="c")

button = tk.Button(frame, text="RetroArch Vulkan", font=60, command=lambda: vulkan())
button.place(relx = 0.05, relwidth=0.4, relheight=1)

button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="RetroArch glcore", font=60, command=lambda: default())
button2.place(relx = 0.55, relwidth=0.4, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works fine using my created `.lnk` file.

Answer (score -1):

Convert to exe using pip install pyinstaller, then pyinstall --onefile (yourapp).py
then run the exe? If you want no console then do pyinstall --noconsole --onefile (yourapp).py